# Why is adoptStyles-css stylesheet link added to every page?

Tags: plugins, css, debug, html

By looking at the source of any of the WordPress pages on my site, I can see there is this stylesheet link:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='adoptStyles-css' 
 href='http://mydomain.com/wp-content/plugins//adopt_styles.css?ver=2.9.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

The link is broken - the URL is not served by my WordPress. (the double slash is not the source of the problem)

Has anyone seen this before? Where does this link come from? How to remove it/determine the plugin that is adding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File with this name comes up in search as part of Adsense Optimizer plugin ([SVN](https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/adsenseoptimizer/trunk/)). Curiously I don't see stylesheet actually being queued in code...

Are you using this plugin? Up to date version?

Comment: Thanks! It was indeed the Adsense optimizer plugin. Installing the latest version fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sould be added by a plugin or your theme. Try disabling them one by one to determine the one which is adding it.